# How to estimate the difference between two Ito diffusions?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d, \sigma:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^{d\times d}$ are measurable functions and satisfy
\begin{equation*}  2\langle −,()−()\rangle +\|\sigma()−\sigma()\|^2 \le |−| \rho(|−|),\ \ \ \ {(1)}\end{equation*}
for all $, \in \mathbb R^d$, where $\rho:[0, \infty)→[0,\infty)$ is some appropriate function. In addition, assume that the SDE
$$()=(())+ \sigma(())()$$
is well-posed in the strong sense.

We now consider the coupled process
$$\begin{aligned} & ()=(())+\sigma(())(), \\ & ()=(())+\sigma(())(),\end{aligned}$$
where $$ is a $$-dimensional standard Brownian motion. Is it true that
for all $t\geq 0$ the following estimate is true?
\begin{equation*}  |()−()|≤\rho(|()−()|)+\left\langle \frac{()−()}{|()−()|},(\sigma(())−\sigma(()))()\right\rangle.\ {(2)}\end{equation*}

Using Ito's formula, we have
$$ |()−()|^2=(2\langle ()−(),(())−(())\rangle + \|\sigma(())−\sigma(())\|^2)+2\langle ()−(),(\sigma(())−\sigma(()))()\rangle.$$
Using (1), and applying Ito's formula to the process $|()−()|^2$ using the function $()=^{1/2}, \ge 0,$ we can formally derive (2). But there is a problem, as $$ is not differentiable at 0. But I don't know how to rigorously prove or disprove (2).

Thanks a lot for your help. (I posted this question in Stack Exchange, but no answer yet).

Comment: Does it help to mollify, with a sequence of smooth functions $F_n(x,y) \to |x-y|$ in some appropriate fashion?  Apply Ito's formula for each $F_n$ and try to pass to the limit.  You'll probably have to bound the quadratic variation of $\left|\nabla F_n(X_t,Y_t) - \frac{X_t - Y_t}{|X_t - Y_t|} \right|$ which seems like it should be possible if $F_n$ is chosen well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I can use the classical Yamada & Watanabe technique (e.g., section 5.2 of Karatzas and Shreve) to derive (2). But is it possible to prove it using Ito-Tanaka formula?